# Why are my deep links (android) opening inside the browser?

Tags: android, google-chrome, deep-linking

Has anyone ever seen a deep link open an app "inside" the browser? I am testing the ability to open our app from a webpage, it all works, but when I click on the link from a non-chrome browser (so far tested the emulator browser and dolphin browser), it appears to open the app, but if you click on the "recent programs" key, you will see the app body but the browser title bar. In addition to this behavior, you can also then open the actual app, essentially allowing 2 instances of the same app to be running (see screenshot).

Any ideas? (btw, it works as expected when you use the chrome browser)

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrpFE.jpg

Comment: like my question and I hope we can find solutions :D 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014389/my-app-screen-appears-in-browsers?noredirect=1#comment53852312_33014389