# My App Screen Appears in Browsers

Tags: android, firefox, opera, deep-linking

I open browser (opera or firefox ) on Android and write my deeplink on address bar
when I press Go button on Browsers ,It redirect me to My app As expected 
but the problem is My app appears on Browser like in Image 
How I can open my app and close the browser after that or make it not display my app screen on it.

[image: my app in opera and firefox]

Comment: what do you mean by deeplink on address bar app not working ?

Comment: I didn't say it is not working , deeplinking is working as I want
the problem is Browsers display my app screen on them as in image I attached

Comment: can you able to post that link if you dot mind

Comment: it like this 
app://product?id=12345

Answer (score 7):

Your app is launched into the browser task. So you have to add

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

to your `<activity>` tag to make your app the root of its own task.

See [android:launchMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for its complete documentation.

Comment: launchMode is not the problem  because this issue not appear on Chrome or Android Browser

Comment: @Ma7moudEl-Naggar I'm not sure, if I follow. But I would guess these Browsers just start the intent as new task automatically.